# Change the classname in each Tag that depends on the href value

Tags: javascript, html

I need to change the class of each href item depending on its value.
I have this code.

```
<body onload="myFunction()">

    <div class="indi-download">
      <div class="pull-left">
    <h6 class="file" id="file-display-id">%file_display_name%</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="pull-right">
      <a class="download-link" id="download_link" href="%file_url%">Download</a>
    </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

In getting the href item on class download-link, I used this javascript code.

```
function myFunction()
{
  var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a.download-link');
  for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    var url = anchors[i].href;
    var splitfile = url.split('.').pop();
    if(splitfile=='pdf'){
       //class="file" would be class="pdf-file"
   }else if(splitfile=="docx"){
       //class="file" would be class="docx-file"
   }else{
      //other file format...
   }
 }
}
```

on Inspect Element, Something this kind of output.

Element 1 ---

```
<div class="indi-download">
<div class="pull-left">
            //Changed into pdf-file
    <h6 class="pdf-file" id="file-display-id">Sample PDF 1</h6>
</div>
<div class="pull-right">
    <a class="download-link" id="download_link" href="http://mysite-  
            info/download/files/file1.pdf">Download</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Element 2 ---

```
<div class="indi-download">
<div class="pull-left">
            //Changed into docx-file
    <h6 class="docx-file" id="file-display-id">Sample docx 1</h6>
</div>
<div class="pull-right">
    <a class="download-link" id="download_link" href="http://mysite-
     info/download/files/file2.docx">Download</a>
</div>
</div>
```

How to achieve this kind of output? Changing the classes that depends on the values on href. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, I think something like this should work:

```
function myFunction()
{
   var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a.download-link');
   for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
     var url = anchors[i].href;
     var splitfile = url.split('.').pop();
     if(splitfile=='pdf'){
       $(anchors[i]).removeClass('file');
       $(anchors[i].addClass('pdf-file');
     }else if(splitfile=="docx"){
       $(anchors[i]).removeClass('file');
       $(anchors[i]).addClass('docx-file');
    }else{
       //other file format...
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The *class* **attribute** is mapped to the *className* **property** so as not to clash with the ECMCAScript future reserved word *class*, so you want something like:

```
anchors[i].className = 'docx-file';.
```

Applied to your example, you can do something like:

```
var classNames = {pdf:'pdf-file', docx:'docx-file'};
...
anchors[i].className = classNames[splitfile];
```

and to accommodate a default:

```
anchors[i].className = classNames[splitfile] || 'default-class';
```

just in case *splitfile* doesn't match one of the expected values. And the entire function is:

```
function myFunction() {
  var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a.download-link');
  var classNames = {pdf:'pdf-file', docx:'docx-file'};

  for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    var url = anchors[i].href;
    var splitfile = url.split('.').pop();
    anchors[i].className = classNames[splitfile] || 'default-class';    
  }
}
```